# Storage vMotion fails with a DMotion error

Tags: virtual-machines, vmware-vsphere, migration, datastore

I've ran into an issue where several servers that I've been trying to migrate to different datastores the past few days are unable to migrate properly. Rather than migrating like normal, the servers are receiving failed attempts to migrate and show the following symptoms:

-The .vmx and some vmware.log files have duplicates in the original datastore and the new one I want to move it to.

-Each time I right click to view one of these VMs, I notice that the complete migration option is available but doesn't work.

-Each time I right click to view one of these VMs, I also notice that Power and Snapshot options are disabled.

Also I've noticed something about a dMotion inside one of the datastores, however I've never seen this before and was not sure what to do. After trying various different things I tried deleting it to see if that could be the problem, however it did nothing. At the moment, I'm trying to learn how to fix this by using an older VM that if it gets wiped by accident, there will be no harm done, that way I can then fix VMs that are being used and having this problem later.

If someone could help me fix this I'd appreciate it. I've been using the following KB article from VMware that I found doing some research, however I'm not too sure on some of the instructions since this is my first time doing this. Below is the link:

http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1009113

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you describe how you are trying to migrate the servers? are you migrating the vmdk (storage only: dmotion) or live-migrating the vms(vmotion)? are you using vcenter?

Comment: I've tried various methods by now. I just now tried manually moving the vmdk from one datastore to another and deleting the duplicate vmdk, however this did nothing to alleviate the errors. I'm migrating just the storage though, and through vCenter.

Comment: More detail on the setup. What type of storage are you using? Is the process failing at a particular percentage indicator?